# MonoTouch.Dialog: Disable Selection Style on entire table

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Currently to tell a cell not to flash blue when selected, I set the Cell's SelectionStyle to none:

```
 cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
```

Is there a way to tell the entire DialogView (TableView) to apply this to all cells in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `SelectionStyle` property is not part of `UIAppearance` and it's also being set by most `Element` in MonoTouch.Dialog (so it would be overridden).

Note that several elements, e.g. `EntryElement`, `UIViewElement`, `BooleanElement`, `FloatElement`..., are already setting the `SelectionStyle` to `None`.

The easiest way is to create new (or subclass existing) `Element` types and set this property (along with others) to match your application style.